How to simplify expression for checking object's fields for undefined value in typescript?
I need to check the textAreaRef.current and textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea for undefined value.
That works:
if (textAreaRef.current && textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea) {
  const currentCursorPosition = textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea.textArea.selectionStart;
}

But that don't:
function isTextAreaExists() {
  return textAreaRef.current && textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea;
}

if (isTextAreaExists()) {
  const currentCursorPosition = textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea.textArea.selectionStart;
}


Error
TS18047: textAreaRef.current is possibly null
TS18048: textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea is possibly null

Are there ways to simplify the expression?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without unrelated errors. For example, we need a declaration of textAreaRef.

Try wrapping the return with an if (textAreaRef != null)

It’s possible to preserve the type guard behavior of the original, but it seems cleaner to use more variables (and maybe the optional chaining operator ?.).
const resizableTextArea = textAreaRef.current?.resizableTextArea;

if (resizableTextArea != null) {
  const currentCursorPosition = resizableTextArea.textArea.selectionStart;
}

or if you don’t otherwise need resizableTextArea,
const textArea = textAreaRef.current?.resizableTextArea?.textArea;

if (textArea != null) {
  const currentCursorPosition = textArea.selectionStart;
}


This works
if (textAreaRef.current && textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea) {
  const currentCursorPosition = textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea.textArea.selectionStart;
}

because Typescript is smart enough to also read the if statement and see if you have checked the parent object exist. However -- textAreaRef.current && textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea doesn't necessarily return a boolean value; it could be either false, the value of textAreaRef.current && textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea if it is valid or null. Because true && 'Hello' evaluates to 'Hello'.
Also, if you store the if in a function, Typescript will not be able to tell if you are actually doing a safety check for your object or not, therefore throwing an error where the object you are using could potentially be null.
Here is a easy workaround by combining the power of optional chaining ?.
const currentCursorPosition = !!textAreaRef.current?.resizableTextArea?.textArea?.selectionStart
  ? textAreaRef.current?.resizableTextArea?.textArea?.selectionStart
  : fallbackvalue

or even simpler
const currentCursorPosition = textAreaRef.current?.resizableTextArea?.textArea?.selectionStart || fallbackvalue

Using ternary here with fallback value is because you do not really want to declare a value inside a if, since it will make the variable outside of the if statement.
Cheers!

you can do it like this based on your question you wana chack textAreRef.current and resizableTextArea in that so you can do it like this and use ternary operator for chacking if you have truthy value you get that
const textArea = textAreaRef.current?.resizableTextArea?.textArea
const selectionStart = textArea?textArea.selectionStart : null

or
or you can use Nullish coalescing operator insted of ternary
const textArea = textAreaRef.current?.resizableTextArea?.textArea
const selectionStart = textArea.selectionStart ?? null

